# Zimbra mail server

Tags: zimbra

Is DNS Configuration required for ZImbra mail server.
 I installed Zimbra with out configuraing DNS ..
I am unable to start mailbox.
              antivirus               Running
        imapproxy               Running
        ldap                    Running
        logger                  Running
        mailbox                 Stopped
                zmmailboxdctl is not running.
        memcached               Running
        mta                     Running
        snmp                    Running
        spell                   Running
        stats                   Running
        zmconfigd               Running

Couls you please help out???

Comment: If you don't get a reply, try the [zimbra community](https://www.zimbra.com/community/) (forum, wiki docs) etc.

Answer (score 2):

A correct DNS configuration is essential for Zimbra to work.

You need a MX record for your domain pointing to an A record. The A record is the hostname of your zimbra box.

You should check `/etc/hosts`. This file must contain a correct entry for your hostname and your IP like this:

```
1.2.3.4 mail.example.com mail
```

Further information can be found at the [Zimbra Wiki](http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/DNS) and in the [Zimbra Forums](http://www.zimbra.com/forums/installation/).

You should also check, that you have a correct reverse DNS entry for your domain.